# Responsive image links in one row

Tags: html, css

[Updated photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd8eW.jpg) I need help with images that are links. I need that 5 images stay in one row at all resultions by resizing. Theese 5 images must be sticked to sides of web. I hope somewho could help me, because i didn´t found anything yet..
Thanks

Image of my resultion, this is what it must look like on every resultion, of course smaller:

[image]

```css
.gallery {
  max-width: 1615px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.photo img {
  width: 316.5px;
  height: 200px;
}
.photo a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.rollover {
  opacity: 1;
  -o-transition-duration: 1s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  background: url(img/plus.png) bottom right no-repeat rgb(28, 28, 28);
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}
.rollover:hover {
  opacity: .7;
  -o-transition-duration: 1s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
}
#roll-text,
#roll-date {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#roll-text {
  margin-top: 70px;
}
#roll-date {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="photo">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/first-image.png">
      <div class="rollover">
        <p id="roll-text">Odťahovanie vozidiel z verejných komunikácií súkromnou spoločnosťou</p>
        <p id="roll-date">24. November 2014</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/second-image.png">
      <div class="rollover">
        <p id="roll-text">Odťahovanie vozidiel z verejných komunikácií súkromnou spoločnosťou</p>
        <p id="roll-date">24. November 2014</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/third-image.png">
      <div class="rollover">
        <p id="roll-text">Odťahovanie vozidiel z verejných komunikácií súkromnou spoločnosťou</p>
        <p id="roll-date">24. November 2014</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/fourth-image.png">
      <div class="rollover">
        <p id="roll-text">Odťahovanie vozidiel z verejných komunikácií súkromnou spoločnosťou</p>
        <p id="roll-date">24. November 2014</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/first-image.png">
      <div class="rollover">
        <p id="roll-text">Odťahovanie vozidiel z verejných komunikácií súkromnou spoločnosťou</p>
        <p id="roll-date">24. November 2014</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the following:

1. `float: left;` to `.photo`
2. `width: 20%;` to `.photo`
3. `width: 100%;` to `.photo a`
4. `width: 100%;` to `.photo img`
5. `height: auto;` to `.photo img`
6. `width: 100%` to `.gallery`

Why?
The images need to flow in a row, so you need to set a value for `float`. Also if you want to have 5 images fit into a row, each photo container has to take 20% of the width (each photo in turn 100% of its container). Set the height to `auto` to make sure the images don't get squashed and keep their aspect ratio. Also make the gallery go from side to side by giving it 100% width.

That should do the trick.

Comment: I understand, but now it looks like this...Im new on this page and i don´t know how to insert image to comment so I upload it to my ask...

Comment: I accidentally set the width of the image itself to 20%. However the image containers should all take up 20%. The a tag and the image both should then take up 100% of the container.

If then there are still layout issues remaining, most probably there is some other CSS interfering with yours, breaking the styles.

I edited my post to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you had a fixed width for the image. Now, this resulted to same width for every resolution.

```
.photo img {
  width: 316.5px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

To fix it add this

```
.photo a {
  width: 20%;

 }

.photo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your css

```
.photo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
 }
```